# How do I create a command on Windows without having to create a file?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch-file, echo

I want to create the command **hello** without having to create a file like **hello.bat**.
I want the command without the file.
The command must execute an **echo Hello World!**.

Is there a way to do it on Windows?

Comment: Just curious, but why? Ultimately it will still be held in a file somewhere, just not one you're controlling directly. I'm very curious as to what the purpose of this objective is.

Comment: My psychic power detect an XY question: I'm guessing that the OP has a `bat`/`cmd` which calls hello.bat, but the hello.bat call never returns. The solution for that is to use `call hello.bat`, rather than eliminating hello.bat.

Comment: I have like 5 .bats and I was wondering if I could get rid of them and still use the 5 commands.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### I want to create the command hello without having to create a file

You can use `doskey`.

1. Open a cmd shell
2. Enter the following command:

   ```
   doskey hello=echo Hello world!
   ```
3. Run the command:

   ```
   hello
   ```

Example:

```
F:\test>doskey hello=echo Hello world!

F:\test>hello
Hello world!

F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [doskey](http://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html) - Recall and edit commands at the DOS prompt, and create macros. You cannot run a Doskey macro from a batch file.

Comment: Note that this *only works within cmd*, e.g. it won't work from PowerShell, etc.. Much like a bash alias, it's shell-specific.

Answer (score 7):

You can create an Environment variable, and then call it using `%hello%`

[image: ![![enter image description here]

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Consider adding the text instruction of the steps to go along with the complimentary screen shots in case the screen shot links ever break, then there will be a lot of detail missing.

Comment: In support of the comment from @PimpJuiceIT, every image has a description of `enter image description here` which makes them somewhat opaque to screen reader software

Answer (score 1):

- For add/create one system variable without using/following GUI:

In command line:

Using **`setx`** command:

```all-bat
rem :: For current user (save in "HKEY_CURRENT_USER")
setx Hello "echo Hello world!"

rem :: For all users (save in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE")
setx Hello "echo Hello world!" /m
```

Using **`reg add`** command:

```all-bat
rem :: For current user (save in "HKEY_CURRENT_USER")
reg add HKCU\Environment /v Hello /d "echo Hello world!" /f

rem :: For all users (save in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE")
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Hello /d  "echo Hello world!" /f
```

---

- In File.reg

For current user:

```all-bat
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment]
"Hello"="echo Hello world!"
```

For all users:

```all-bat
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment]
"Hello"="echo Hello world!"
```

---

Using:

```all-bat
C:\>%hello%
Hello world!
```

---

---

For removing by command line:

For current user:

```all-bat
reg delete HKCU\Environment /v Hello /f
```

For all users:

```all-bat
reg delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Hello /f
```

For removing by File.reg

For current user:

```all-bat
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment]
"Hello"=-
```

For current all users:

```all-bat
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment]
"Hello"=-
```